# Navigation Button is not working correctly in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

[Chef Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4jyJ.png)  I have Written following code for UI.

Attached Image is the UI which will be generated with the following code. My Navigation buttons are not working properly. I Need navigation from one page to another. It is doing but on the small screen it doesn't work well.

```
BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Gray" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="../Images/C_Transparent.ico" FontFamily="Tahoma">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Themes/MenumateTheme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:PercentageConverter x:Key="percentageConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Name="OuterGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".60*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height=".1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".9*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="#F09422" >
        <Label FontSize="24"   Content="Items Summary" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <!--<Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">-->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".15*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".15*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".15*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".15*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource FunctionButtonStyle}"  Command="{Binding AutoUpdateCommand}" Grid.Column="0" Content="Update UI" Background="#FFF09422" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource NavigationButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding NavigateLeftCommand}"
                    Name="LeftNavigationButton">
            <Path Data="M 0 0 L 0 40 L5 40 L 5 20 L 40 40 L 40 0 L 5 20 L 5 0  Z"/>
        </Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource NavigationButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding NavigateBackwardCommand}"
                    Name="BackwardNavigationButton">
            <Path Data="M 0 20 L 40 40 L 40 0 Z"/>
        </Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource NavigationButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding NavigateForwardCommand}"
                    Name="ForwardNavigationButton">
            <Path Data="M 0 0 L 0 40 L 40 20 Z"/>
        </Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource NavigationButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="4" Command="{Binding NavigateRightCommand}"  
                    Name="RightNavigationButton">
            <Path Data="M 0 0 L 0 40 L 35 20 L 35 40 L 40 40 L 40 0 L 35 0 L 35 20 Z"/>
        </Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource FunctionButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="5" Background="#FFF09422"  Command="{Binding CloseCommand}">Close</Button>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListBox x:Name="ItemSummaryList"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource   percentageConverter}, ElementName=ItemSummaryList, Path=ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=.99}">
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Name="S1" Orientation="Vertical" Width="{Binding Converter={StaticResource   percentageConverter}, ElementName=ItemSummaryList, Path=ActualWidth, ConverterParameter=0.5}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="1" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#C4D3C4" Background="#C4D3C4" Margin="0,2,0,2">
                            <Label FontSize="34" Content="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            </Label>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource FormLabel}" Foreground="Red" Content="{Binding StatusText}"></Label>
</Grid>
```

I want navigation from one page to another.

For backward Navigation I have written following.

```
private void Backward(object sender) 
{ 
    var scroller = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(ItemSummaryList);  
    ItemOffset = System.Convert.ToDouble(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth); 
    scroller.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scroller.HorizontalOffset - ItemOffset); 
}
```

Comment: Can Anyone answer this question please?

Comment: Could you explain, what's not working actually?

Comment: When I am pressing navigation button my screen should move the third column(Next Page). At Screen Having resolution 1920*1080 it works fine but not on 1366*768 it is not moving correctly(just some sort). You can see the attached image.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what's wrong on the picture? I see two columns with items in it. You mean something about the borders of the items?

Comment: And have you considered not to do the paging with the wpf visuals, but rather with data logic? Maybe something like here https://www.codeproject.com/kb/wpf/wpf_paging.aspx  
Could save you memory for long lists.

Comment: @AndreasH I have devided screen in two parts. If one column filled, than second column start and so on. ie repeated columns. So My purpose was if i press navigation button then screen should show column 3,4 ie; Page 2 again pressing navigation button then column 5,6 ie; Page 3

Comment: @user3193035 I understood that intention, but for me the picture shows exactly that.

Comment: @AndreasH. Yes picture shows exactely but problem is in navigation. All is working fine except navigation.